# Text or images over search button CSS

Tags: css, button, joomla

I have a problem in my website. In some browsers like Safari, Opera, IE6, and Chrome; I get the text help (or image help) that appears when an image doesn't exist or couldn't be loaded. It appears over the lupe (search button), that is loading correctly in every browser. For example in Opera it shows the text "Image" over the lupe, in Safari a blue "?", and in Chrome it appears a image with geometric figures.

In Firefox it works fine. I don't know if its a css problem. By the way I am using Joomla 1.7.

The code for loading the image is:

```
#search .search .button {
background: url("../images/search_but.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 26px;
    border: medium none;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix your missing images, it'll disappear.

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: there are no missing images, www.balloncesto.com

Answer (score 0):

You have `src="/"` and `type="image"`
Which is wrong

Either use:

```
<input type="image" value="Buscar" src="../images/search_but.gif" onclick="this.form.searchword.focus();">
```

or

```
<input value="Buscar" class="button" onclick="this.form.searchword.focus();">
```

Comment: I am not using html for this. Its loaded with CSS.

Comment: Exactly the actual image is loaded with css in the class="button" but it is trying to load an image src="/" this is why you get the error

Comment: It must be happening inside Joomla because I can't find the code you are talking about.